# systemd initiated uwsgi process shuts down after a while

Tags: uwsgi, systemd

So I wrote this simple systemd service script:-

```
[Unit]
Description=uwsgi server script

[Service]
User=web
Group=web
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/prod/myproject/releases/current
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'source ~/.bash_profile; workon myproject; uwsgi --ini /var/www/prod/myproject/releases/current/myproject/uwsgi_prod.ini'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which works fine - it starts up and I can see my uwsgi processes in `htop`.

However, it inexplicably shuts down after being idle for 5 minutes.

If I start this process manually in bash console by executing, as web user:-

```
source ~/.bash_profile
workon myproject
uwsgi --ini /var/www/prod/myproject/releases/current/myproject/uwsgi_prod.ini
```

my process does not die after being idle.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it after chatting with another dev on `systemd` channel.

Adding this into the `[Service]` section solved the problem:-

```
Type=forking
PIDFile=/tmp/project.pid-3030
```

The reason is simple. If `Type` isn't declared, the default is `Type=simple`, which expects the process does NOT fork so when `bash` exits, `systemd` thinks the process is dead and tears down the cgroup.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, you need to specify the `Type` otherwise `systemd` defaults to `Type=simple`.

However, the [official uWSGI docs on managing uWSGI with `systemd`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Systemd.html) use `Type=notify` rather than `Type=forking` because then there's no need to specify the `PIDFile`.